# VBScript and Float (double) numbers: Round function returns wrong result

Tags: vbscript, floating-point, floating-accuracy, ieee-754

such code in VBScript will return wrong result:

```
MsgBox Round(4.99985,4)
```

It will return `4.9998` but correct result is `4.9999`. I know that it is related to how VBScript works with numbers with floating points, that some numbers can't be represented in binary system, but please tell me:

1. What exactly happening here?
2. What is the possible workaround for that?

Thanks!

Comment: You might be interested in this article I wrote, which is related: http://www.exploringbinary.com/inconsistent-rounding-of-printed-floating-point-numbers/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is expected result, so called [bankers' rounding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bankers_rounding). Check out the [description of the `Round` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se6f2zfx%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) (bold added by me):

> The Round function performs *round to even*, which is different from *round to larger*.
>   ...
>   If expression is exactly halfway between two possible rounded values, the function returns the possible rounded value whose **rightmost digit is an even number**.

To round to larger, you can use the following function (taken from [here](http://ewbi.blogs.com/develops/2003/11/vba_round_yet_a.html)):

```
Function RoundToLarger(ByVal Number, ByVal NumDigitsAfterDecimal)
  RoundToLarger = CDbl(FormatNumber(Number, NumDigitsAfterDecimal))
End Function
```

(Note: Negative numbers are rounded down.)

Comment: The interesting thing is the double rounding that's going on. 4.99985 is 4.9998500000000003495870259939692914485931396484375 in double precision. That should round up to 4.9999. But VBScript is first rounding it to 15 digits (presumably), getting 4.99985, and then rounding again to even, getting 4.9998.